# transforming a symmetric matrix to positive definite matrix with diagonal as ones.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a symmetric matrix $A$ with $1$'s as a diagonal element. I want a function $B=f(A)$, so that $B$ becomes non-negative definite matrix with diagonals as $1$'s.

For example, $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
 2 & 1 & 4 \\
 3 &4 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It's pretty unclear what this means. The function $f(X) := I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, obviously satisfies the condition, but $f$ doesn't actually depend on $A$, suggesting this isn't what you're looking for. What other conditions must $f$ satisfy?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want any generic function which can transform A to B conditions applied. Not any specific transformation like identity matrix. like B=A^2 can make it non-negative definite, but it wont be symmetric and diagonals wont be 1's anymore. Is there any function that I can operate on only upper (or lower) diagonal elements and make a matrix non-negative definite? I dont want want the diagonal 1's to be changed. Like say, i want correlation matrix which has 1's as diagonal and is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: I've down voted because the Question is unclear.  The function given in the previous Comment satisfies the stated requirements, and you've discarded that solution without articulating why.

Comment: That's your viewpoint. I have not discarded the answer. I just said that I need a more generic answer as I am working on real data. The answer Travis provided was of great help and I appreciated it as I have to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user152715 said, symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues and is diagonalisable.

So first find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A. You then can write $A = P*D*P^T$

Let's call $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ the three eigenvalues. Here you are searching a matrix $f(A)$ that is diagonalisable and has eigenvalues$>0$. The best way could be to simply search B such that A + B is diagonalisable, has is diagonal equal to 1 and is positive definite. In general case it will happen when the diagonal of B equals to 0 (obvious), and B is diagonalisable into the same basis in which A is diagonalisable, with eigenvalues that compensate A's eigenvalues.

So you're searching a matrix of the form $B = PGP^T$ such that G is a diagonal matrix and that $$G = \begin{pmatrix} x- \alpha & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y-\beta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & z-\beta\end{pmatrix}$$ with $x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq0$.

You also want that:
$$PGP^T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & * & * \\ * & 0 & * \\ * & * & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Now just resolve this system (find $x$,$y$ and $z$) and you will find B.

This is a generic method, but it won't always give you a solution ($x,y$ or $z$ can be negative). I'm not sure you will find a generic solution for this.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this...

Comment: If this is what you were searching you can mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

A symmetric matrix has real eigen value and positive definite symmetric matrix has all positive eigen value. Can you take from here?